# Smooth scroll text in grid column wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a Grid with 3 columns. I want to scroll a long text, which I update using a ticker in my second column. I tried textblock, but if my text don't fit in, it will cut my string down. Can you recommend me something to do that.

My code looks like this now:

Here are the three column.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The textblock which I update

```
                    <TextBlock Name="SongTitle" Text="Now onair:" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap">
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate" />
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <TextBlock.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
```

Here is some problem, it starts to scroll not from the column edge...

```
<DoubleAnimation 
                            From="300" To="0" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="translate" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                            Duration="0:0:8" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </TextBlock.Triggers>
                    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, instead of using a `Grid`, you should be using a `ScrollViewer`. To hide the scrollbars, set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Hidden`. You can then handle mouse wheel events through code-behind to prevent the user from manually scrolling the text.

Of course, it is also possible to use a `Grid`, but it will give you a bunch of headaches.

To answer your original question, you should be using `LayoutTransform` instead of `RenderTransform`.